# How do you get canvas% objects to respond to mouseovers?

Tags: canvas, scheme, racket, mouseover

Right at the moment, I've got a window that looks like this:

[image]

Each of those green disks represents a number. How can I make it so that when you move the mouse over the disk, a tooltip or something appears and shows you the number?

That's only one simple illustration, of course. The goal is to see in general how to do this without writing lots of new code for every case.

Currently, I'm drawing a single big 'pict' image to the canvas, which appears to be the wrong approach. Rewriting it to work some other way is no big deal. I just need to know what the right approach is: which tool, which library, how are you intended to put the things together to implement a mouseover.

I've been searching the Racket documentation but haven't found any clear answer to this question so far.

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend the `canvas%` class with a new [`on-event`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/canvas___.html?q=on-event#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._canvas~3c~25~3e%29._on-event%29%29) method. The `on-event` method takes in a [`mouse-event%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/mouse-event_.html?q=on-event) object, that contains contains the mouse's `x` and `y` coordinates with the respect to the target window.

From there, you can compare it to whatever data structure you are using to calculate where to draw the circles on the canvas.

So something like this should work:

```
(define clicky-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (define/override (on-event e)
      (define window-x (send e get-x))
      (define window-y (send e get-y))
      (when (eq? (send e get-event-type) 'left-down)
        .... your code here ....)))
```

Now you can just insert your `clicky-canvas%` object into the window where you had previously inserted the `canvas%` object.

Comment: So, does this mean that racket/gui won't send a mouse event to an object on the canvas?

Comment: For `canvas%` you are correct, it won't. For `editor-canvas%`, it will. And in that case, you'll probably want to add `(super on-event e)` to your overridden method.

Comment: Could you take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803324/1393162) below? It's probably way more code than you want to see, but hopefully skimming it will make clearer where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to implement adding tooltips to arbitrary labeled images. It most likely does it clumsily and incorrectly. I offer it here to illustrate my confusion. Hopefully you can post an answer that shows an approach that makes more appropriate use of the many tools in racket/gui. Known problems are marked in comments in the code and briefly discussed below.

[image: A tooltip on an arbitrary pict]

```
#lang debug at-exp racket/gui

(require (prefix-in pict: pict) pict/snip mrlib/snip-canvas)

;; Adding tooltips to windows ==========================================

;CONFUSION: This is needed only because pane% doesn't support client->screen.
;Is the reason why it doesn't also a reason why this function shouldn't exist?
(define (window-parent-of window)
  (let ([parent (send window get-parent)])
    (cond
      [(not parent)
       #f]
      [(is-a? parent window<%>)
       parent]
      [else (window-parent-of parent)])))

;CONFUSION: Is the documentation on client->screen or get-current-mouse-state
;wrong?
(define-values (screen-x-offset screen-y-offset)
  (let-values ([(xo yo) (get-display-left-top-inset)])
    (values (- xo) (- yo))))
(define (window-top-left-in-screen-coordinates window)
  (let ([parent (window-parent-of window)])
    (if parent
      (let-values ([(wx wy) (send parent client->screen (send window get-x)
                                                        (send window get-y))])
        (values (+ wx screen-x-offset) (+ wy screen-y-offset)))
      (values (send window get-x) (send window get-y)))))

(define (in-window? window point)  ; <--- CODE SMELL: reinventing the wheel?
  (define-values (wx wy) (window-top-left-in-screen-coordinates window))
  (define-values (ww wh) (send window get-size))
  (define-values (px py) (values (send point get-x) (send point get-y)))
  (and (<= wx px (+ wx ww))
       (<= wy py (+ wy wh))))

(define (text->tooltip-pict text)
  (let* ([text (if (pair? text) (map ~a text) (string-split (~a text) "\n"))]
         [text-image (for/fold ([text-image (pict:blank)])
                               ([line text])
                       (pict:vl-append text-image (pict:text line)))]
         [text-image (pict:inset text-image 4 2)]
         [background (pict:filled-rectangle
                       (ceiling (pict:pict-width text-image))
                       (ceiling (pict:pict-height text-image))
                       #:color "LemonChiffon"
                       #:draw-border? #t)])
    (pict:cc-superimpose background text-image)))

(define -pict-canvas%  ; <--- CODE SMELL: reinventing the wheel (pict.rkt)
  (class canvas%
    (init-field pict
                [style '()])
    (inherit get-dc)
    (define/override (on-paint)
      (pict:draw-pict pict (get-dc) 0 0))
    (super-new [min-width (exact-ceiling (pict:pict-width pict))]
               [min-height (exact-ceiling (pict:pict-height pict))]
               [stretchable-width #f]
               [stretchable-height #f]
               [style (cons 'transparent style)])))

(define tooltip-window%
  (class frame%
    (init-field text
                point ; will place window above this point
                [pict (text->tooltip-pict text)])
    (define width (exact-ceiling (pict:pict-width pict)))
    (define height (exact-ceiling (pict:pict-height pict)))
    (super-new [style '(no-resize-border no-caption float)]
               [label ""]
               [width width]
               [height height]
               [stretchable-width #f]
               [stretchable-height #f]
               [x (exact-ceiling (- (send point get-x) (/ width 2) 3))]
               [y (exact-ceiling (- (send point get-y) height 8))])
    (define canvas (new -pict-canvas% [pict pict] [parent this]))
    (send this show #t)))

(define TOOLTIP-HOVER-DELAY 600)
  ;When mouse cursor sits motionless over relevant window for this long,
  ;tooltip appears.

(define tooltip-mixin
  (mixin (window<%>) (window<%>)
    (init-field [tooltip (void)]
                [tooltip-window #f])
    (super-new)

    (define (maybe-open-tooltip-window)
      (define-values (point buttons) (get-current-mouse-state))
      (when (and (null? buttons) (in-window? this point))
        (set! tooltip-window (new tooltip-window% [text tooltip]
                                                  [point point]))))

    (define timer
      (new timer% [notify-callback maybe-open-tooltip-window]))

    (define/public (close-tooltip-window)
      (send tooltip-window show #f) ;<--- MEMORY LEAK: Should close, not hide
      (set! tooltip-window #f))

    (define/override (on-subwindow-event receiver e)
      (if (and (not (void? tooltip))
               (eq? this receiver)
               (eq? 'motion (send e get-event-type)))
               ;STRANGE: We never get 'enter or 'leave events
        (begin
          (if tooltip-window
            ; If tooltip is showing, mouse motion closes it
            (close-tooltip-window)
            ; Mouse motion followed by a pause opens it
            (send timer start TOOLTIP-HOVER-DELAY #t))
          #t)  ; UNSURE: What is on-subwindow-event supposed to return here?
        #f))))
      ;BUG: Often no 'motion event comes when the mouse leaves this window,
      ;so the tooltip stays up.

;; Labeled dots with tooltips ==========================================

(define fr (new frame% [label "xtooltip"] [width 200] [height 100]))

(define hp (new horizontal-pane% [parent fr] [alignment '(left top)]))

(define pict-canvas% (tooltip-mixin -pict-canvas%))

(define (disk d)
  (pict:cc-superimpose
    (pict:ghost (pict:disk 50))
    (pict:disk d #:color "aquamarine" #:draw-border? #f)))

(define (make-dot parent label activation)
  (define vp (new vertical-pane% [parent parent]
                                 [stretchable-width #f]
                                 [stretchable-height #f]))
  (define l (new message% [parent vp] [label label]))
  (define d (new pict-canvas% [parent vp]
                              [pict (disk (* 8.0 activation))]
                              [tooltip activation]))
  vp)

(define d1 (make-dot hp "archetype4" 4.1))
(define d2 (make-dot hp "some-sa-node" 2.26))
(define d3 (make-dot hp "this-dot" 0.4))

(send fr show #t)
```

Some of the code is marked "reinventing the wheel", such as `in-window?`, because it duplicates functionality likely already implemented in the Racket libraries. (Some parts borrow ideas directly from their source code.) I figure that a smarter approach would leverage what the libraries already do rather than implement it anew.

This version lets you easily add tooltips to most GUI elements, such as messages and buttons, but it doesn't use a `canvas` or `editor-canvas`. Consequently it doesn't allow scrolling over a larger number of labeled dots than can fit in the window. I figure that the next thing to do is derive a [`snip%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/snip_.html?q=client-%3Escreen) class to draw a tooltipped `vertical-panel%` holding the label and the dot. But since a snip needs to draw itself on a drawing context, I'm not sure how to do that. In any event, it's clearly time to ask someone more experienced with racket/gui to suggest an approach more in line with how the library works.